# Why 'present(_:animated:completion:)' can be a parameter of #selector when it doesn't have @objc?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

i studied #selector that it's parameter methods must need @objc. but i encoutered a code like this.

```swift
let selector = #selector(present(_:animated:completion:))
```

and present method doesn't have @ojbc.

```swift
 @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

why this could be possible?

it's because of present method existed before swift as 'presentViewController'?

Comment: It isn't marked as `@objc`, since it is an Obj-C method that's bridged to Swift. `UIViewController` (and most UIKit types actually) are written in Obj-C, not in Swift.